# << operator doesn't evaluate expressions correctly

Tags: c++, stream, overloading, operator-keyword

I made a Vector class in c++, and my problem is that if I do

```
Vector v = v1 + v2;
cout << v
```

result is correct, however doing
`cout << v1 + v2` gives

`[-1.07374e+008 -1.07374e+008 -1.07374e+008]` instead of `[1, 2, 4]`

same goes for other operators I implemented,
here is my + operator implementation

```
Vector& Vector::operator+= (const Vector& other) {
    x += other.x;
    y += other.y;
    z += other.z;
    return *this;
}

Vector& operator+ (const Vector& v1, const Vector& v2) {
    Vector v = v1;
    v += v2;
    return v;
}
```

and << operator

```
ostream& operator<< (ostream& o, const Vector& v) {
    o << "[" << v.x << " " << v.y << " " << v.z << "]; ";
    return o;
}
```

I didn't menage to find an error and what I have here seems correct. Anyone could tell why this happens?

Comment: In `operator+`, you are returning a reference to a local variable with automatic duration. That's undefined behavior. You should return it by value instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Return the new vector by value:

```
Vector operator+ (const Vector& v1, const Vector& v2)
//    ^ no '&'
```

You're returning a reference to a local variable, which has been destroyed by the time you can use the reference. Your compiler should warn about this; make sure you're compiling with all sensible warnings enabled.

Comment: thanks, my compiler told me nothing. So as far as I understand what I did worked but not always because doing this kind of thing is 'undefined', or is there another explanation why it worked in some circumstances?

Comment: Compiler must have raised a warning!

Comment: @Ajay: Only if warnings were enabled. Sadly, some compilers don't enable them by default.

Comment: @user3758262: Using a destroyed object is indeed undefined behaviour. It might appear to "work" if the object's memory hasn't been reused, so it still contains something that looks like the dead object. In the first case, you immediately copy it to a local variable; the chances are that it hasn't been reused at that point, so it appears to "work". In the second, you pass the reference on to `<<`, which is likely to reuse the memory itself, giving garbage. But in both cases, the behaviour is undefined, and in principle anything could happen.

Comment: all right, thank you a lot. I'm using vs2013 and now I changed warning level to 4 and indeed I've received this warning